# JS wait for custom UI

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

This code overloads js alert

```
<div id="alert" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 id="alert-title" class="modal-title">ALERT!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="alert-text">One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

window.alert = function () {
  $("#alert-text").html(arguments[0]);
  if (arguments.length > 1)
    $("#alert-title").html(arguments[1]);
}
```

but the behaviour is wrong; alert is no longer blocking. So it morphed into this

```
var wait = {};
function waitFor(id){
  if ($("#" + id).attr("aria-hidden") == true)
    wait[id] = false;
  else
    setTimeout(waitFor,300,id);
};

window.alert = function () {
  $("#alert-text").html(arguments[0]);
  if (arguments.length > 1)
    $("#alert-title").text(arguments[1]);
  wait.alert = false;
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#alert").modal();
    waitFor("alert");
  }, 300);
  while (wait.alert) {
    //do nothing
  }
}
```

Now it pauses, but stalling the UI thread is a dismal idea since it interferes with rendering.

I could turn alert into a promise but that's not backwardly compatible.

Is it possible to create a drop in replacement for alert, or should I give up and just modify every call to alert?

---

Per accepted answer below the code becomes

```
  <div id="alert" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
            aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 id="alert-title" class="modal-title">Message from application</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="alert-text">One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="alert-close" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

alert = function () {
  $("#alert-text").html(arguments[0]);
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    $("#alert-title").html(arguments[1]);
  }
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $("#alert-close").one("click", function () {
    deferred.resolve("resolve");
  });
  $("#alert").modal();
  return deferred;
}
```

And you'd call it like this

```
alert("This is the text for the <b>alert</b> containing markup", 
  "This is a custom title").done(function () {
  $(document.body).append("<p>This runs AFTER the alert closes<p>");
});
$(document.body).append("<p>This runs BEFORE the alert closes");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create a complete, drop-in replacement for `alert()` with the exact same interface and blocking capability because there is no way to simulate that blocking capability that `alert()` has in your own Javascript.

You would have to use a non-blocking routine and thus would have to change the interface so the caller can know when the alert is done and continue their processing (like with Promises as you proposed).